# Light does not affect particles in my simulation

Tags: three.js

I am trying to add lighting to an old n-body simulator that I wrote a few years back, but simply adding and configuring the light does nothing.  As well as this, I have attempted to change the existing ParticleCanvasMaterial to MeshLambertMaterial for the particles, but this simply makes them invisible!

I don't know if this is expected to work on the old version (not sure how to find the number!), but I have no reason to think it won't . . .

I was defeated in installing the latest version because of the new module stuff that I don't understand.

Anyhow, the code is at https://github.com/m4r35n357/NBody3DJs/tree/mrdoob, a diff with the master branch will reveal the small changes that I have made in my attempt.

Hope someone can help, I think some shadows will make the thing much easier to see!

**Update**: I have also been grepping the js for additional methods, found none relevant.  Also tried light.castShadow and particle.receiveShadow to no avail.

**Another update**: I am trying to use the latest three.js, but getting

```
Module source URI is not allowed in this document: “file:///home/ian/projects/NBody3DJs/js/three”.
```

When I attempt to use the "module" approach.

**Further update**: when running from the Python HTTP server I get:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: THREE is not defined
    init http://localhost:8000/main.js:26
    <anonymous> http://localhost:8000/main.js:13
main.js:26:5
Uncaught TypeError: Error resolving module specifier “three”. Relative module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”. localhost:8000:20:33
asm.js type error: Disabled because no suitable wasm compiler is available es-module-shims.js
Uncaught TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource. es-module-shims.js:766:26
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
```

**Another update**: I have now removed my sim altogether, just trying to load index.html/css and three!

```
Uncaught TypeError: Error resolving module specifier “three”. Relative module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”. localhost:8000:20:33
asm.js type error: Disabled because no suitable wasm compiler is available es-module-shims.js
Uncaught TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource. es-module-shims.js:766:26
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think `THREE.Particle` exists. Not sure where you're getting that class from, but maybe you want to use [`Points` and `PointsMaterial`](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=Points#api/en/materials/PointsMaterial)? At any rate, points do not cast shadows because they're not a real Mesh geometry, since they have no thickness.

Comment: Well it is obviously an obsolete class; I am not creating it!  I suppose my only chance is to get this working with the latest three.js, but it works differently now . . .

Comment: Sounds like you haven't used Three.js in a long time. I think you need to start [with the new installation guidelines](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Installation) and perhaps going over [how to run things locally](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/How-to-run-things-locally).

Comment: Yes, I am trying that now, but I can't get three to load from inside the project, even using a basic web server.  See updates.  I originally built the sim from an example, so I never had _that_ deep an understanding ;)

Comment: I now suspect the shims URL from https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Installation

Comment: You can see [a working demo of the shims here](https://jsfiddle.net/bpc16q4w/). You can replace with `https://unpkg.com/three@0.141` if you want to target a specific revision (r141 in this case).

Comment: I'm not a js dev, just a part time hobbyist, so I'm not sure what I should be doing on that page to "see them in action" (I hit the "run" button and nothing seemed to happen)!  What I _can_ see is that the importmap there is _different_ from the one on the doc page I posted above.  Also, I am already using that version in my shims URL.

Comment: At this point, I am beginning to lose motivation; it seems that even if I _can_ get the installation instructions to work, the _one_ object class that I am interested in (Particle) is now gone.  At least I had the foresight to embed that old, working, three.js in my project.